# How to abort script running in Microsoft's ScriptControl

Tags: c#, vbscript

I'm using Microsoft's ScriptControl to run a VBScript in a C# application. I've registered a few custom objects using the AddObject method for extra functionality. I would like the script to abort when the one of the custom object's methods is called with bad parameters. Generating an exception, even of type COMException, makes ScriptEngine retry executing the code! Yes, that was surprising.

So the big question is: what can I do in my C# code that is called from ScriptEngine that will make the running script abort (preferably disclosing exception information).

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the `ScriptControl` is doing that and there isn't an `On Error GoTo` statement doing something interesting? Or some loop in your C# code? If what you say is accurate than any code that always throws an exception would produce an infinite loop. (Or, to put it differently -- can you give a reproducible example?)

Comment: The infinite loop is indeed what I'm seeing. I'll see what I can do to come up with a short reproduction scenario and code. But not today. Bed time!